# Show Hidden Files OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: finder, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show hidden files and folders in finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-finder)

How do I show the hidden files in OS X 10.7 Lion?

Comment: The hidden preference here is the same as other recent OS X. - changing lion tag to OS X

Comment: what about the user's library files?

Comment: There's a question for that too :-)  http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/17797/5472

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Terminal.app (Applications > Utilities) and type the following commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

To undo re-open Terminal.app and run

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
killall Finder
```