# How do your library folder back?

Tags: macos, folders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the ~/Library folder go in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17797/where-did-the-library-folder-go-in-lion)

I upgraded to Lion but now under ~/User there is no library folder. What happened to it? Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and type:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

Look here for more information:

http://www.macgurulounge.com/library-folder-mac-os-lion/

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you hold "Option" while in the Finder's Go menu, it'll add a Library entry. Useful to know how to get there if you don't need constant access.

Answer (score 0):

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

If you just need to browse into it on someone else's computer, open a Finder window, press cmd+shift+g and then type ~/Library.

Comment: Unsure who's to blame for not searching first, but: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17797/where-did-the-library-folder-go-in-lion