# How do I tell Finder to always show my Library folder on Mavericks?

Tags: finder, macos, library

I thought there was a checkbox to suppress the hiding of my user Library folder on Mavericks, but I can't seem to find it. I appreciate hiding Library by default, but [since Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17797/where-did-the-library-folder-go-in-lion) have missed it being easily accessible.

How can I get the library folder to be visible in Finder, the Finder go menus / file save dialogs without needing to hold down shift?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open your desired user Home folder in Finder (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) and select **View > Show View Options**. There should be a checkbox for toggling the Library folder.

[image]

Comment: That absolutely shows me the Library in file save dialogs and Finder views. Now to see if we can leverage that to get the Finder Go menu as well :-) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's odd that it still doesn't show up in the Go menu after enabling it in Finder. Is that a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 5):

Apple decided to hide the Library from its users in recent OS X updates, but in Mavericks you can now change that with a simple checkbox.

In the past you had to enter a Terminal command with every little system update:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

With OS X Mavericks, you can just navigate to your home folder, press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to bring up the folder settings, and **check the box** next to **"Show Library Folder"** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Even without Admin privileges, you can use the Finder's Go menu to access the library folder. Click on Go, then choose *Go to folder...* near the bottom of the dropdown menu.

In the resulting dialog box, type

> ~/Library

and hit Return.

**EDIT:** Alternatively click Go press <kbd>⌥</kbd> and click Library as it will show up on the key-press.

Your Library folder will open in the active Finder window, or in a new window if one isn't already open.

Comment: The downside of this method being that there is no (one step) keyboard shortcut for doing that.

Comment: @dwightk hit the ALT button and it will show up as item in the list.

Comment: Absolutely, you can always "go" to the location whether it's visible or not. I was really hoping to document how to influence the visibility which is what the accepted answer provides. This is a true statement, and I'm not sure where the admin comes into play - did you mean to edit the answer that's chosen to explain when it won't work?

Comment: @bmike changed via review page - I cannot see the full question there? Feel free to rollback.

Comment: @robuust that's cool, then it shows up which lets you bypass the Go to folder command, but oddly there's no keyboard shortcut next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you first drag over your Home Folder to the side bar if it's not already there. Then click on it and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.